# Не виводит компонент на страницу сайта

Tags: reactjs, api, asp.net-web-api

делаю первую свою апишіку.
Пишу в реакте.
Проблема:Не хочет виводить компонент Department в вкладке Department, не виводит This is Department page.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот файл App.js:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

import {Home} from './Home'
import {Department} from './Department';
import {Employee} from './Employee';
import {Navigation} from './Navigation';

import {BrowserRouter,Router, Route, Switch, Routes} from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <div className="container">
      <h3 className="m-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
        React JS Tutorial
      </h3>

      <Navigation/>
        
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' component={Home} exact/>
        <Route path='/department' component={Department} />
        <Route path='/employee' component={Employee} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Вот Department.js(не виводит This is Department page.):

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';

export class Department extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="mt-5 d-flex justify-content-left">
                <h3>This is Department page.</h3>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Вот Navigation.js:

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';
import { Navbar,Nav } from 'react-bootstrap';

export class Navigation extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <Navbar bd="dark" expand="lg">
                <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav"/>
                <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                <Nav>
                    <NavLink className="d-inline p-2 bg-dark text-white" to="/">
                        Home
                    </NavLink>
                    <NavLink className="d-inline p-2 bg-dark text-white" to="/department">
                        Department
                    </NavLink>
                    <NavLink className="d-inline p-2 bg-dark text-white" to="/employee">
                        Employee
                    </NavLink>
                </Nav>
                </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Navbar>

        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Если версия react-router 6 , поменяйте во всех Route component на element  https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#relative-routes-and-links

Comment: @Алексей спасибо, помогло